# Can't link against Boost.Thread 1.46.1 with MinGW 4.5.2

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, boost-thread

I've built boost using:

```
bjam --toolset=gcc --with-thread stage
```

Whenever I'm trying to actually use Boost.Thread I'm getting undefined references although I link against it. It doesn't happen with other Boost libraries like Regex or System.

```
>g++ main.cpp -I. -L. -lboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_46_1
C:\Users\jhasse\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjYfDox.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread20hardware_concurrencyEv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Example program:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the compiler option '-DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB'

Comment: Hello, i just tried this method to use Boost and i get the linker error too, and when i use said compiler option, it gets moved to the #defines section of my options. Im using Code Blocks with MinGW and im using this option in `Compiler Settings->Other Options`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the compiler option '-DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB'

Comment: +1; where is that documented? I can't find any notice about that in the boost thread 1.49 documentation. The boost 1.50 documentation has an unfinished sentence about defines in the top-level page about the thread library.